# Transaction backed out with reason: 'The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '100'

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

I am using JBOSS 7 to host my MDB and IBM MQ as my messaging provider. I am using wmq.jmsra.rar resource adapter to communicate to IBM MQ.

If Message1 is consumed by MDB, we are storing message content into DB. Due to field validation it can't able to store and throwing exception. We handled that run time exception and MDB code running good. Now, Instead of picking Message 2 from queue, MDB keep on picking again message 1 and processing again and again.. we are getting below error in log file.

```
2018-02-08 18:53:19,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (default-threads - 17) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4026:Transaction backed out with reason: 'The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '100'.'.
2018-02-08 18:53:19,448 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default-threads - 17) ARJUNA016045: attempted rollback of < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a5b844a:bacea37:5a7c20fa:897, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a5b844a:bacea37:5a7c20fa:898, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=unknown eis name > (com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper@3d6ba018) failed with exception code XAException.XAER_NOTA: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_rollback' has failed with errorCode '-4'.
```

Comment: If the XA transaction is meant to commit both the MQ GET and the DB INSERT as one unit of work, if the DB INSERT fails the message will be backed out to the queue.  If you view the message on the queue you will note a field in the MQMD called Back out count.  This should increment each time it is backed out.  The MDB will also look at two queue level settings, BOQNAME and BOTHRESH.  If these are filled in, the MDB will move the "bad" message to the queue named in BOQNAME if at get time the back out count is equal to the BOTHRESH.

Comment: If the above would solve your problem let me know and I'll write it up in answer form.

Comment: Dear Josh, how we can handle that infinite loop of picking same message again and again from MDB java point of view.

Comment: Hi Pramod, I proposed a solution above, if you want me to write it up confirm this will work for you.  It will essentially try to process the message the number of times you set as BOTHRESH, if it exceeds this number it will move the message to the queue you specify in BOQNAME.  Those are both queue manager side settings so the MQ administrator will need to set them.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc, I will get in touch with MQ team..

Comment: Dear @JoshMc, i got in touch with MQ team. We created Back out queue for existing queue and the message infinite loop issue resolved, But our  concern is we have around 100 queues , is it suitable to create backout queue for each one ? any other alternate solutions available for this issue?

Comment: don't use XA? :)

Comment: Can you confirm what you would do with a failed message that went to the BO queue?  Do you need to do anything with these or do you prefer to just dump them in some way?

Comment: Dear @joshMc, i want to dump them..

Comment: Dear @joshMC, Just on informational point of view, from MDB side we handled all exception from java side in our catch block. If we deploy our MDB in IBM WAS its working fine for poison message, but there is no BOQNAME  and BOTHRESH configured for that queue. If we deploy same MDB in Jboss using resource adapter we are getting this infinite message processing issue. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: I don't know the answer to why this would not be a problem in WAS but is in Jboss.  Multiple queues can have the BOQNAME point to a single queue.  You could make this queue an alias to a TOPIC object which has a topic string that is not subscribed to by anything.  This would throw the messages away.

Comment: Dear @JoshMc,  when you suggested don't use XA transaction. Where we can configure that setting in JBoss application server???

Comment: I'm a MQ admin not a JBOSS admin, so not sure.  Have a look at our MDB.  It sounds like you have a global transaction that includes both the MDB reading messages from the queue AND the database update.  If the DB update fails then the message would be backed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the WARN message and it can be assumed that MQ has discarded the transaction's work, since XAER_NOTA indicates that the transaction is no longer known to the resource adapter.

Comment: MQ discarded transaction work, i agree with this point. But my MDB keep on picking same message again and again processing and failing again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using IBM MQ JCA 7.5.0.6 or later.  I believe that you are hitting a known error in the IBM MQ JCA.

Comment: Dear Doug, We are using WMQ JCA version 7.5.0.7 version

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very delayed response, nevertheless posting my experience as it may be useful for others.

I have seen similar issues. In my case, we were using ARJUNA transaction manager, which was hiding the actual issue and throwing a generic error. Please see my blog for more details
https://jjsrambles.wordpress.com/2019/09/05/the-method-xa_end-has-failed-with-errorcode-100-or-the-method-xa_prepare-has-failed-with-errorcode-4/

Regards